# remove a file called -l from command line (Centos)

Tags: unix, command-line

Someone accidentally created a file name '-l' and I cannot remove it, because `rm -l` interprets the filename as a flag. I've tried quotes, escaping and nothing is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In virtually all Unix commandline utilities you can use a double-dash `--` to separate options from arguments. Under the hood, [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) will stop attempting to parse arguments as options when it first encounters a `--`. From the docs:

> getopt has three ways to deal with options that follow non-options argv elements. The special argument ‘--’ forces in all cases the end of option scanning.

In your specific case with `rm`, use:

```
$ rm -- -l
```

Comment: For completeness, the other "standard" solution to this type of problem is to use a different pathname for the same file but which doesn't have the form of an option, most simply `rm ./-l`.